# Visual Studio XML Schema annotations (vs:htmlequivalent)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xsd

I'm creating an xml schema for a document that will eventually be translated into javascript. It would be really useful to allow the insertion of custom js scripts right within the document. This isn't hard to accomplish (a node can just contain text, that will be the javascript), but what is difficult is to get Visual Studio to give JS Intellisenseinside the tag instead of xml Intellisense.

If found this article that describes htmlequivalent annotation that says you can tell the xml editor to treat a tag as the equivalent HTML tag (in this case the script tag, and this is even the example given). But my attempts at using it have failed. Does anybody have any ideas on how to use this? There is very little documentation on msdn about this annotation and about the same on google/bing.

The MSDN article regarding the annotation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa713989(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no documentation available for newer XML Schema annotations - the one on MSDN is for VS2003. Your best bet is to check out the already available XML Schemas in the folder:

[VSInstallFolder]\Common7\Packages\schemas\html\

The HTML5 one should give you a good overview of the available features. There are even more features in XML Schemas in WebMatrix 3 beta, like supplemental Schemas, but they are still not available in VS.

However I'm not sure that the functionality you're trying to achieve is possible.